# handling empty columns in apache poi

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have a program reading excel sheet from a java program.

I am iterating over cells as below:

```
Iterator cells = row.cellIterator();
String temp;
StringBuilder sb;
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");

while (cells.hasNext()) {
Cell cell = (Cell) cells.next();
temp = null;

    switch (cell.getCellType()) {
         case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
         temp = cell.getRichStringCellValue().getString();
         break;

    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:

    if (DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)) {
        temp = sdf.format(cell.getDateCellValue());
       } else {
             temp = df.format(new BigDecimal(cell.getNumericCellValue()));
       }
          break;
          default:
     }
    if (temp == null || temp.equalsIgnoreCase("null")) {
        sb.append("").append(";");
    } else {
        sb.append(temp).append(";");
    }
 }
```

As seen, I am trying to create a string builder containing values from excel row in semicolon separated way.

Issue is, if a column value is empty, I want it as an empty value in the string builder with two consecutive semicolons.

However, the call

> Cell cell = (Cell) cells.next();

simply ignores the empty cells and jumps over to next non empty cell.

So the line

> if (temp == null || temp.equalsIgnoreCase("null"))

is never met.

How to get a handle on empty column values as well in the iterator ?

Comment: normally I would use getCell() and check whether it is null

Comment: are you appending a semicolon for every empty?

Comment: @BhavikShah: Yes.. I want to..

Comment: I cannot chat it is blocked by my organisation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is virtually a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13048981/read-excel-file-2010-apache-poi-ignoring-empty-cells), and so [my answer to that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13048981/read-excel-file-2010-apache-poi-ignoring-empty-cells/13051187#13051187) basically applies exactly to you too.

The Cell Iterator only iterates over cells that are defined in the file. If the cell has never been used in Excel, it probably won't appear in the file (Excel isn't always consistent...), so POI won't see it

If you want to make sure you hit every cell, you should lookup by index instead, and either check for null cells (indicating the cell has never existed in the file), or set a `MissingCellPolicy` to control how you want null and blank cells to be treated

So, if you really do want to get every cell, do something like:

```
Row r = sheet.getRow(myRowNum);
int lastColumn = Math.max(r.getLastCellNum(), MY_MINIMUM_COLUMN_COUNT);

for (int cn=0; cn<lastColumn; cn++) {
   Cell c = r.getCell(cn, Row.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL);
   if (c == null) {
      // The spreadsheet is empty in this cell
   } else {
      // Do something useful with the cell's contents
   }
}
```

Comment: what's the use of selecting max of r.getLastCellNum() and MY_MINIMUM_COLUMN_COUNT? You think that really brings value to your solution?

Comment: @AndreyM.Stepanov Yup, some people know they always want eg 10 columns of values, if they're doing a table-like extraction

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
int previous=0;
while(cell.hasNext())
{
    Cell cell = (Cell) cells.next();
    int current=cell.getColumnIndex();
    int numberofsemicolons=previous-current;
    for(numberofsemicolons)
    {
    sb.append("").append(";");
    }
    previous=current;
}
```

or you can do

```
int numberofcells=row.getFirstCellNum()-row.getLastCellNum();
for(i=0;i<=numberofcells;i++)
{
     Cell cell = (Cell) cells.next();
     int current=cell.getColumnIndex();
     while(i<current)
     {
        sb.append("").append(";");
        i++
     }
}
```

Comment: Thats the issue.. Cell cell = (Cell) cells.next(); call is ignoring empty columns. But I feel your code is handling that.. can you please explain a bit..

Comment: getColumnIndex() will give you the cell number. for example you previous column is 2 and current column is 5. then you want to add 3 semicolons

Comment: How to get size of Cells ? If I can get that, I can use for loop instead of while, which will solve the issue.

Comment: size?? as in the width? or the number of cell between 2 cells

Comment: No.. the number of elements in Cells... I mean total number of columns (null as well as non null)...

Comment: row.getPhysicalNumberOfCells() but this would give you not null cells. try going with the hard way. _row.getFirstCellNum()-row.getLastCellNum();_

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18902/discussion-between-bhavik-shah-and-nikunj-chauhan)

Answer (score 0):

Answer posted by @Gagravarr works perfectly for me but MissingCellPolicy is an enum now, so while getting the cell value instead of using

```
Cell c = r.getCell(cn, Row.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL);
```

I have used

```
Cell c =r.getCell(cn,Row.MissingCellPolicy.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL);
```