# iterating over the columns of a row through poi in java

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have a excel file named abc.xls in my c: drive (local computer) , now in that excel file in the first sheet itself there is a table as shown below and this below table can lie in any range  with in the sheet so i have developed the below java program which will scan the entire sheet first by row basis and then on column basis and will find the cell where
TradeRef is there

```
 TradeRef   TMS  Deal     Date        
    12      45   DRT    23/97/2014      
    23      36   QWE    21/07/2015
```

now the problem in my below program is that it captures the cell where TradeRef is there and then it iterates over the columns and then in similar fashion it captures the next row and iterating over the columns

but the logic that i want to apply is that when it captures the TradeRef cell  and iterating over the columns and reached to the last column of the table which is Date in the above table then it should further  scan the next 20 columns within the same row  and if within the next 20 columns there is no cell having any value then it should move to the next row and if within the 20 columns it mite be that any cell can have value then in that case it should read that cell value

so it would be like

```
 TradeRef   TMS  Deal     Date          <----- scan next 20 columns is there is no value in next 20 cells then move to next row else include that cell value also------->
    12      45   DRT    23/97/2014        
    23      36   QWE    21/07/2015
```

so please advise how to implement the above logic of scanning the next 20 columns within the row below is my earlier implementation  that is

```
public class AAA {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {


        FileInputStream file = null ;
         try {

                 file = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\abc.xls"));
                HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(file);
                HSSFSheet firstSheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
                Iterator<Row> iterator = firstSheet.iterator();

                Cell c = findFirstRow(firstSheet);
             }




             catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally{
                file.close();
            }

    }

    public static Cell findFirstRow(HSSFSheet firstSheet) {
          for (Row row : firstSheet) {
            for (Cell cell : row) {
                  cell.setCellType(cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
              if ("TradeRef".equals(cell.getStringCellValue())) {
                int row1 = cell.getRowIndex() + 1;
                int col = cell.getColumnIndex();
                if (firstSheet.getRow(row1) == null)
                  throw new RuntimeException("Row " + row1 + 1 + " is empty!");
                Cell startOfFirstDataRow = firstSheet.getRow(row1).getCell(col);
                if (startOfFirstDataRow == null) {
                  CellReference ref = new CellReference(row1, col);
                  throw new RuntimeException("Data not found at " + ref.formatAsString());
                }
                return startOfFirstDataRow;
              }
            }
          }
          throw new RuntimeException("TradingRef header cell not found!");
        }


}
```

so please advise how can i implement the above logic of scanning next 20 columns

Comment: row.cellIterator knows the number of cells very well, scanning further is possible (row.getCell) but is entirely pointless

Comment: possible duplicate of [Read excel file 2010 apache poi ignoring empty cells](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13048981/read-excel-file-2010-apache-poi-ignoring-empty-cells)

Comment: @ammoQ Thanks for the advise please request you tu show how  can we scan the next 20 columns please

Answer (score 0):

First, you should probably use the `org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel` API, which work with all Excel files while the `HSSF*` classes only work with `.xls` files.

The `org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet` class has a [`getFirstRow()`](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#getFirstRowNum()) method that you can use to start your search. Next you want to find a sequence of Cells containing the given Strings, like:

```
// This is an array containing the headers
final String[] headers = { "TradeRef", "TMS", "Deal", "Date" };

// now we take row from above to be the Row object where we seek our headers
int last = row.getLastCellNum();
for (int c = row.getFirstCellNum(); c < last; c++) {
    int h = 0;
    // check if the cell at (c + h) has the required value
    for (; h < headers.length && c + h < last; h++) {
        if (!headers[h].equals(row.getCell(c + h).getStringCellValue())) {
            break; // if the cell value differs from our header
        }
    }
    if (h == headers.length) // this means the break was never invoked 
        return c; // found it
}
return -1; // not found
```

Comment: @IIogiq Thanks a lot for the solution can you please advise in detail what that piece of code is doing please, request you to if you can please complete this code as I have shown above that will help to understand a lot thanks a lot

Comment: @llogoq request you to please if you can integrate your piece of code in mine one shown above please Thanks in advance

Comment: @erertgghg just a heads-up: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267490/thanks-in-a-comment – also this is a place to ask and answer questions, not get someone to do your code for free.

Comment: @illogiq please t least try to explain what the above piece of code is doing at least i have gone through the comments section but not able to grasp completely i request you to again please embed this piece of code into mine code so that i can completely understand the flow end to end please

Answer (score 0):

if you want to skip column you can use

```
while (cellsInRow.hasNext()) {
     Cell currentCell = cellsInRow.next();

     if (currentCell.getColumnIndex() >= 3 && currentCell.getColumnIndex() <= 6) {
         continue;
     }
         }
```

to skip column 4, 5, 6 and 7 from excel file. index starts at 0